# iOS TabBar Item, increase size of icons

Tags: ios, iphone, uiview, uitabbar, tabbar

I want to make its size like in Instagram app, but did not have any frame properties here.

How can I increase size of tabBar icon?
Is it possible ?

Comment: select your Bar item >> set image inset  Top :5 Bottom :5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible with the standard UITabBar. You need to create your own customized UI element, like Instagram did. For the standard UITabBar, the maximum size is about [25 by 25 pixels](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH27-SW1) (50x50 if you have a retina-screen).